# Is sanitize_text_field() is enough to save to DB?

Tags: database, security, sanitization

So here is the situation. We allow users to enter input data, i.e. user_first_name and user_additional_comments.
Then we use sanitize_text_field() , which is named as save.

But after this filter:

`Thomas' OR SELECT * FROM wp_user`

Is still save into DATABASE as full text. And `'` char is not escaped as `&#39;` or `\'`.

I use `$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO A (a,b,c) VALUES ('{$a}', '{$b}', '{$c}')");` So $a has to be a valid value here, which can be inserted into db. I have reasons not to use insert(), prepare() etc. specific functions, so I need to be sure that $a is VALID and SECURE. How to ensure that for text data like last name, or comment.

So is this brokes the security?

Comment: Are you saving these through raw SQL or `update_*()` functions? If it's the former then you'll need to also use [`prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) - other than that, `sanitize_text_field()` is a normal sanitization function which is fine in most cases.

Comment: I don't wan't to use prepare(). I use `$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ... $x");` . I need a solution without prepare.

Comment: valid what? secure for what purpose?

Comment: Updated the message. Valid text so that it could be inserted into db, and won't break db on insert process (i.e. will not drop other table or do something bad)

Comment: You want to be secure but you want to reinvent security oriented API. This doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [wpdb insert](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) function. It's better in every way.

It can care about data's escapeing itself and it's shorter.

You can use your own query anyway but I would recommended this article for reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database